# How to rename multiple files using a windows batch file script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have and will have files which are named "x_1.txt x_2.txt x_3.txt, ..." my other program where I input these files cannot recognize the order so it sorts like this "x_1.txt , x_101.txt , x_2.txt"). a solution is to rename the files to x00001.txt  , x00002.txt , ....
I have so far wrote the .bat file below, but two problems I have which , I'd be very glad if you help me solve them :

1- how can I remove the 'number'.txt from string x_'number'.txt

2- (solved) how can I use the variable of this string to rename the file name ( the rename part of this file is not working!)

```
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A count=100000
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   set /a count+=1
   set str=!count:~1!
   echo !str!
   echo %%f
   set filename=%%f
   set filename=!filename:~0,5! /Comment: here I want to just keep the x_ part which I don't know how"
   echo !filename!
   set str3=!filname!!str! 
   echo !str3!
   /// ren %%f !str3!.txt  /Comment: Here I cannot use the variable str3,
   call:renamer %%f !str3!
 )

 :renamer
 ren %1 %2.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it would be better to fix the other program. :)

Comment: @Golez, This I know :), but first a batch file is the only compiler I have in hand now! I can use MATLAB but then I have to run matlab every time I want to do it
Second, I remember when I was a kid and I was installing programs in DOS they used batch files to make a very nice program that could do everything. I promissed myself one day I would learn it! the time has came to learn it :D

Comment: I fixed the 2nd question by adding a call to a subroutine in the end of the file, I am updating the post

Comment: now I just need to split the string of X_'number'.txt from _

Comment: oops the script is wrong it doesn't do in correct order! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following conditions are true:

- You want to rename all of your .txt files in the current folder
- All of the .txt files have exactly one `_` in the name, immediately before the number
- None of your file names contain `!`

Then the following will work

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.txt) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%A in ("%%F") do (
  set num=0000%%B
  ren "%%F" "%%A!num:~-5!.txt"
)
```

But to eliminate the conditions requires much more complicated code.

Here is one robust solution that should properly rename all files that meet the template.

- It allows for multiple `_` in the name.
- It only renames files with a name that ends with `_NNN.txt` where NNN is a number
- It properly handles `!` in the file name.

Note that it will not properly handle numbers that exceeds 99999. It is simple to expand the degree of 0 padding.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
subst #: .
#:
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt^|findstr /er "_[0-9]*.txt"') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ("!name:_=\x!") do (
    endlocal
    set "file=%%F"
    set "name=%%~pA"
    set "num=%%~nA"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "num=0000!num:~1!"
    set "name=!name:~1,-1!"
    ren "!file!" "!name:\x=_!!num:~-5!.txt"
    endlocal
  )
)
popd
subst /d #:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe in the power of this Bat files :) I understood the second code (J/k :-)). but I couldn't get the use of token in first code,
if you have time could you explain where the parameter %%B is set?

Comment: Ok i got it %%B is the second token